# Debian 7 Nginx HHVM server not running hh code

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I have an nginx Debian 7 server I have configured for hhvm successfully before (with hh code working fine) but this week I did it again (from a fresh install of Debian 7) and it installed successfully and even responds "HipHop" when i request the phpinfo(). What it doesn't do is load any page with hh code.

I am trying to do:

```
<?hh 
echo "HHVM v".HHVM_VERSION; 
?>
```

on a page called test.php, but the page just hangs.
php code runs fine just not anything in the hh code tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in `/var/log/hhvm/error.log`, you'll see something like `Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_HH_ERROR, expecting $end in /var/www/test.php on line 2`. This is because closing tags are invalid in Hack. This is because closing tags (`?>`) aren't valid in Hack. To have your example work, use:

```
<?hh
echo "HHVM v".HHVM_VERSION;
```